# Setting up server for other people to connect using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have a very small and simple server based on QTcpServer which just listens for new connections and once a new connection is connected it shows message about it.
Respectively, the same thing with my client. So, if i give my client app to my friend how can he connect to my seerver??? I have tested my server and client on locallhost (127.0.0.1) but never tried in the "real" world??? Can you please give me some hints???

```
//**SERVER**
    #include <QTcpServer>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        QTcpServer server; //used 127.0.0.1 for localhost, but...
        server.listen(???, 12345);//--->what to do to connect to the internet


        return a.exec();
    }
```

How can my friend connect to my server?

```
//**Client**
    #include <QTcpSocket>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        QTcpSocket client;

        client.connectToHost(???);    

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: You need to use the external ip address of your server in both addresses. `127.0.0.1` will only allow local connections.

Comment: Also if this is windows the firewall and UAC may get in your way.